# QPushButton with Image not getting highlighted when focused (MAC)

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have a QPushButton with image, i have set focus policy to strong focus but, while focusing that QPushButton it is not getting highlighted(no dot frame or default blue border)

Comment: how are you passing the focus??

Comment: In designer view focusPolicy - Strong focus

Comment: Is there any stylesheet on your button?

Comment: yes, border:none; but i tried removing it, but no effect(not getting highlighted).

Comment: There's some attempt at a description here, but it's difficult to help when a concrete example is lacking. Can you throw together a [mcve] that reproduces this issue? Additionally, state what macOS version and Qt version you're using as that may help.

Comment: If you apply a stylesheet on your button, it will lose the default look-and-feel and you also have to handle the focus with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `QPalette`(in **Qt Designer**) of your `QPushButton` and in particular, the `HighLight` color which is supposed to handle this effect. Moreover, make sure you didn't define `focusPolicy` in the stylesheet of a parent of that `QPushButton`, as that could cause problems, because `QPushButton` would inherit that property.